# Issue with Content Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to html and css. I am trying to customize the slider as provided on this:

http://slidesjs.com/#overview

I am using the - Linking demo from the download.

The only thing I have done so far is add a folder under img, css and js  called slider and have added the files under that folder.

So the only difference in the index.html is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider/global.css">
```

which earlier was:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"/>
<script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"/>
```

everything works fine except the pagination at the bottom of the image frame.
if I restore the path for css from "css/slider/global.css"  to "css/global.css"
it works fine. I tried to locate the places where the *.css file is called but I ma not able to locate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 132 in the css file references a 'pagination' image path. If the location has changed then you'll need to update that css file.

Ex.

```
    background-image:url(../img/pagination.png);
```

Based on what you said above, it should probably now read:

```
    background-image:url(../../img/slider/pagination.png);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have changed the path to               /img/slider/pagination/   everything works fine till I move the 'global.css' to a different location other than /css/global.css  I was looking at the slides.min.jquery.js it has references of 'href' but I am very new to this technology to understand what it is doing.  \Can I ask another question. Iam trying to use two slider on the page. so if I copy the slider content from container div on my html it shows the placeholder for the 2nd slider but doesn't show the content. any help on this  please.

Comment: Cool - if that worked can you accept the answer? Also regarding your other questions: 'href in js' - dont worry about href's; the only thing that should affect something showing up correctly is in the css where it's looking for a url. Check your global for any path updates as well. Next - regarding the 2nd slider; you need 2 main divs with containers and content and the id of the second container div should be different. So you would have  $("#slides").slides(); and  $("#slidesTwo").slides();

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my query. It took me a while to figure how to accept the answer. I will try to rectify the code and bother you if I have any other issue. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi Syon, Thank you for your advice. I am now able to get two slider on my page. the next issue I am facing is the second slider is text only and requires different css. So i created a different css file : text.css  it has all the same element as global.css just that i changed the div name for slide container etc. when i run the html i was getting error. after debugging it I found the js file :'slides.min.jquery.js' using css element: next, prev, slides_container

Comment: I created another js file slides.text.jquery.js replaced the next, prev and slides_container with the text.css element : nextT, prevT, slides_containerT but this is not working. could you please help.

Comment: @user1891297 You shouldnt need to do all of that. If you're just changing the overall container id from 'slides' to something else, then it should work fine. However, if you change the name of any of the elements inside, such as 'slides_container' then the styling will break - but the top level ID should not alter the appearance. (based on what I saw in the js file)